# No value given for one or more required parameters. OleDbException was unhundled vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledbexception

am new to vb.net i have a project vb.net connect to access 2003 database and i want to insert data through vb.net to access data base am using Sql commands here is the code bt it's not working for me

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO info(nam, employed, ple, mertebe, navonishan, sermoche, moche, dxindin, dbemoche, brwaname)" + " VALUES (" & Me.NamTextBox.Text & ",'" & CDate(Me.EmployedDateTimePicker.Text) & "','" & CInt(Me.PleTextBox.Text) & "','" & CInt(Me.MertebeTextBox.Text) & "','" & Me.NavonishanTextBox.Text & "','" & CDate(Me.SermocheDateTimePicker.Text) & "','" & CInt(Me.MocheTextBox.Text) & "','" & CByte(Me.DxindinCheckBox.Checked) & "','" & CByte(Me.DbemocheCheckBox.Checked) & "','" & Me.BrwanameTextBox.Text & "' );"
```

Comment: Required reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use parametrized query.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO info(nam, employed, ple, mertebe, navonishan, " & _
                  "sermoche, moche, dxindin, dbemoche, brwaname) VALUES (" & _
                  "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Me.NamTextBox.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Convert.ToDateTime(Me.EmployedDateTimePicker.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Convert.ToInt32(Me.PleTextBox.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Convert.ToInt32(Me.MertebeTextBox.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Me.NavonishanTextBox.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Convert.ToDateTime(Me.SermocheDateTimePicker.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", Convert.ToInt32(Me.MocheTextBox.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", Me.DxindinCheckBox.Checked)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", DbemocheCheckBox.Checked)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", Me.BrwanameTextBox.Text)
```

A part from the string concatenation, in this way you don't risk to pass a value intended to be a number or a date with the wrong formatting rules (your numeric or date values should not be enclosed in single quotes).

Of course this avoid also the Sql Injection problems stated by other (Cody Gray) in comment